# Trying to print the state in my landing page

Tags: arrays, reactjs, state

I have this state:

```
inputData: {
      id: 1,
      inputArr: ['aaa', 'bbb']
    }
```

Im trying to map him and to make him show in my page but it doesnt work:

```
const test = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map(r => {
      <p>{r}</p>;
    });
```

like so:

```
return (
      <div className="app">
         {test}
      </div>
    );
```

anybody knows why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your `map` function, you're not returning anything. You need to either make it a shorthand function without  `{}`, or have a `return` statement

```
const test = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map(r => {
  return(<p>{r}</p>);
});
```

Or

```
const test = this.state.inputData.inputArr.map(r => 
  <p>{r}</p>;
);
```